# if you know an image's dimensions, how do you scale it without a reflow in a fluid container

Tags: css, responsive-design, fluid-layout

i know the dimensions of the image, but it's located in a fluid container (the red area, resize the window width). i want to avoid reflows, meaning i don't want the size of the red area to ever change.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/AfmFH

how can i setup the html/css so that no reflow occurs?

Comment: If you don't ever want the div to change size why are you setting it fluidly? Or do you mean that you don't want the dimensions of the div to change?  A little clarification would be great because I can't see the reflow happening.

Comment: The width of the div is set by the browser window. Yes, I don't want the size of the div to change, which is the red area.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may just be looking for overflow: hidden on the div. The only down side is if you expand the image too much it won't fit in the div.

```
div {
  width: 50%;
  background-color: red;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: this doesn't do anything. the image is never outside the div

Comment: Did I not understand? I thought the question was how to change the size of the image without expanding the containing div.

Comment: I don't want the size of the div to change as the image is loaded.